# How to send firebase to multiple users with individual notification content

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I'm attempting to send Firebase to multiple users including individual notification content.
We can send the same notification to multiple users with the below code in C#:

```
var message = { 
    registration_ids:['id1','id2','id3'],
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello There...!', 
        body: 'this is test notification' 
    }
};
```

But is it possible to send individual notification to multiple users in one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request to FCM to send a message, will send the exact same message to all recipients in that call. There is no personalization of the messages for individual recipients within a single call.

If you want to send personalized messages to recipients, you'll need to make a separate call for each message variant.

---

**Update**: if you use the newer versioned API to [send a message to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices), you *can* now specify a different message body for each user.